# Get ip address of client from the server

Tags: sockets, struct, ip-address

I'm trying to get the ip address of each of my clients that connect to my server. I save this into fields of a struct which I sent to a thread. I'm noticing that sometimes I get the right ip and sometimes the wrong one. My first peer to connect usually has an incorrect ip...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `inet_ntoa()` returns a pointer to static memory that is overwritten each time you call `inet_ntoa()`.  You need to make a copy of the data before calling `inet_ntoa()` again:

```
struct peerInfo{
    char ip[16];
    int socket;
};  

while((newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&clt_addr, &addrlen)) > 0)
{
    struct peerInfo *p = (struct peerInfo *) malloc(sizeof(struct peerInfo));

    strncpy(p->ip, inet_ntoa(clt_addr.sin_addr), 16);
    p->socket = newsockfd;

    printf("A peer connection was accepted from %s:%hu\n", p->ip, ntohs(clt_addr.sin_port));

    if (pthread_create(&thread_id , NULL, peer_handler, (void*)p) < 0)
    {
        syserr("could not create thread\n");
        free(p);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Thread created for the peer.\n");
    pthread_detach(thread_id);
}

if (newsockfd < 0)
{
    syserr("Accept failed.\n");
}
```

Comment: should memory be allocated to p->ip?

Comment: It already is.  In my example, `ip` is a fixed length array. It is included in the full size of `peerInfo` when calling `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa:

> The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given
>   in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation.
>   **The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which
>   subsequent calls will overwrite.**

Emphasis added.

Comment: In other words, you need to make a copy of the data that `inet_ntoa()` returns, you cannot save the returned pointer as-is.